# Can`t import magento sql database

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm trying to install Magento on a localhost, but when I try to import the sql database, it freezes. Also, i can't access phpmyadmin anymore, neither other website hosted on localhost.

I thought the file was too large, but I increases post_max_filesize and upload_max_filesize. I also increased the maxmimum_execution_time to a higher value.

I've seen that after I turn on xampp again, the database is partially uploaded, sometime with 143 queries or 200+ queries.

What should I do to upload the entire database?

Comment: Your on the right track with changing execution time, I had to change mine to a ridiculous number  to get it to work and it took ages to install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a commandline mysql import:

```
mysql -p -u username database_name < file.sql
```